# Why requests can't access the secured page on this website?

Tags: javascript, python, post, get, python-requests

I'm trying to access the secured part of this website: https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/#login with this code:

```
import requests,time,lxml

LOGIN = 'https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/#login'
PROTECTED_PAGE = 'https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/#avoirs'
payload = {
  'identifiant': '000000',
  'pwd': '111111',
}

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(LOGIN, headers=headers, data=payload)
    time.sleep(2)
    f = s.get(PROTECTED_PAGE)
```

I got both post & get a 200 status code but I can see that I'm not connected. So I'm guessing that there are missing arguments in my payload, but can't figure which.

This is the code of the form (there is no hidden field):

```
<form name="formulaire" role="form" class="form-horizontal form-margin" autocomplete="off">
   <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-11">
         <div class="form-group "><label for="identifiant" class="control-label"><i key="ui.page.login.identifier" class="i18n_resource">Identifiant</i> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign aPopoverTrigger i18n_resource" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-apopovercontent=".aPopoverContent_identifiant" data-original-title="Identifiant"></span> <span class="aPopoverContent_identifiant hidden"><i key="ui.page.login.identifier_description" class="i18n_resource">Votre identifiant correspondant à votre numéro de compte, indiqué sur vos relevés de compte d'Epargne Salariale &amp; Retraite ou votre certificat d'affiliation de votre contrat PER Entreprises.</i></span></label> <input id="identifiant" name="mail" class="form-control" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">  <span class="help-block"><small class="more pointer login_lost"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span> <i key="ui.page.login.forgot_identifier" class="i18n_resource">J'ai oublié mon identifiant</i></small></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-11">
         <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="pwd" class="control-label"><i key="ui.page.login.password" class="i18n_resource">Mot de passe</i> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign aPopoverTrigger i18n_resource" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-apopovercontent=".aPopoverContent_pwd" title="" data-original-title="Mot de passe"></span> <span class="aPopoverContent_pwd hidden"><i key="ui.page.login.password_description" class="i18n_resource">S'il s'agit de votre 1ère connexion, votre mot de passe provisoire vous a été adressé dans un pli sécurisé.</i></span></label> 
            <div class="input-group"><input name="password" id="pwd" class="form-control" required="" type="password" readonly="readonly" value="" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR4nGP6zwAAAgcBApocMXEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=&quot;);"> <span class="input-group-addon"></span></div>
            <span class="help-block"><small class="more pointer password_lost"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span> <i key="ui.page.login.forgot_password" class="i18n_resource"> J'ai oublié mon mot de passe</i></small></span> 
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
         <div id="num-pad"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">1</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">3</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">5</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">6</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">0</button> <br><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">4</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">7</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">8</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">2</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">9</button> </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="text-center"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary i18n_resource" value="Valider" data-loading-text="Patientez..."> </div>
</form>
```

Chrome network developper's tools:
Screenshot here:
[image: Screenshot here]

I can see that there is an authenticate step with a post to https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/authenticate, and the requested payload is my exact payload (username/password). What am I missing? Something on the cookies side (shouldn't be that handled by the session object?) Or one of the page is loading some JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

**I suggest trying to make your headers match:**

(which is what's expected according to `request headers` in console log)

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie: EXCV-20480=OHCBPNAKFAAA; TCPID=11890166566815122122; xtvrn=$566107$; xtan=-; xtant=1; TC_OPTOUT_categories=1; TC_OPTOUT=0@@@008@@@ALL; TCID=201890168471812763405; TCSESSION=201890168479863869083
Host: www.amundi-ee.com
Origin: https://www.amundi-ee.com
Referer: https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.75 Safari/537.36
```

This is what seems to be expected.

Additionally the payload for me is this:

```
payload = {
    'username': '000000',
    'password': '111111',
}
```

Not

```
payload = {
  'identifiant': '000000',
  'pwd': '111111',
}
```

I realize this could be a translation thing but I would still double check to be sure your payload types are correct. To find this out you can look at the `request payload` in console log.

Once these corrections are made/validated it should workout for you! Just let me us know.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt you have to check the right http request on browser

```
POST https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: www.amundi-ee.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 35
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: https://www.amundi-ee.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7
Cookie: EXCV-20480=ODCBPNAKFAAA; TCPID=1181011512189835414503; xtvrn=$566107$; xtan=-; xtant=1

{"username":"313","password":"730"}
```

Second , build request same as it.

Change:after test, server response status code is 400 and said json data error. Then i change my code,send data as json. When that time status code is 403 as same as i login unsuccessfully in browser.

```
import requests,time,lxml
import json
url = "https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/"
LOGIN = "https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/authenticate"
PROTECTED_PAGE = "https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/#avoirs"
payload = {"username":"000000","password":"111111",}

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36",
            "Referer":"https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "DNT": "1",
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Origin": "https://www.amundi-ee.com"}

with requests.session() as s:
    req = s.post(LOGIN, headers=headers, json=json.loads(json.dumps(payload)) )
    time.sleep(2)
    f = s.get(PROTECTED_PAGE,cookies = req.cookies , headers = headers)
```

Request:

```
POST https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: www.amundi-ee.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7
Origin: https://www.amundi-ee.com
DNT: 1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 44

{"username": "000000", "password": "111111"}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, this is not working, f object shows me that I'm still not connected.
I don't understand why is that...

Comment: Also, why verify = False? It is https?

Comment: @Matthieu Because i using fiddler to catch post request. i think today is unfortunate day,i cannot get a cookies same as browser.

Comment: @Matthieu i have changed my code, and get same status code as browser

Comment: Ok I updated my code to enable requests debugging :

`try:
    from http.client import HTTPConnection
except ImportError:
    from httplib import HTTPConnection
HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True`

Remaining as your code, but still not working... Getting crazy.
Following comment showing debug info from requests:

Comment: `DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.amundi-ee.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://www.amundi-ee.com:443 "POST /psf/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1857
send: b'POST /psf/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.amundi-ee.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nReferer: https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nDNT: 1\r\n`

Comment: `Origin: https://www.amundi-ee.com\r\nContent-Length: 46\r\n\r\n'
send: b'{"username": "000000", "password": "111111"}'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date header: Server header: Last-Modified header: ETag header: Accept-Ranges header: Vary header: Content-Encoding header: X-UA-Compatible header: Content-Length header: Content-Type header: Set-Cookie header: Keep-Alive header: Connection 
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://www.amundi-ee.com:443 "GET /psf/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1857`

Comment: `send: b'GET /psf/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.amundi-ee.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nReferer: https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nDNT: 1\r\nOrigin: https://www.amundi-ee.com\r\nCookie: EXCV-20480=OCCBPNAKFAAA\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'`

Comment: `header: Date header: Server header: Last-Modified header: ETag header: Accept-Ranges header: Vary header: Content-Encoding header: X-UA-Compatible header: Content-Length header: Age header: Keep-Alive header: Connection header: Content-Type`

So from requests side, I think everything works. Seems I just got logging issue(s).
Just can't get my hand where is it...

Comment: I found out that there is a Javascript on this page called : 
https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

Could it be the reason why I'm having those trouble?

Comment: i not sure about it. But logining data was sent to  https://www.amundi-ee.com/psf/authenticate and the post raw does not see anything associated with javascrip except cookies.                 Can you tell me what the difference between successful post raw and my `requests` post raw (apart from user/pd)